# I just bought a 2011 Chevy

Tags: chevrolet, leak, water

I just purchased a 2011 Chevy HHS and when I got home last night the floor board and carpet in the front passenger seat was very wet.  I'm guessing this might be a condensation issue. Anyone have any idea what could be causing this to happen.

Comment: The evaporator drain is blocked - allowing the moisture to spill inside the car cabin.

Comment: As Mike said ... this is the drain for the A/C unit (in layman's terms).

Comment: That or a heater core is leaking, but the fluid would have a sweet smell.